# How to extract JSON embedded on a HTML page using C#

Tags: c#, json

The JSON I wish to use is embedded on a HTML page. Within a  tag on the page there is a statement:

```
<script>
jsonRAW = {... heaps of JSON... }
```

Is there a parser to extract this from HTML? I have looked at json.NET but it requires its JSON reasonably formatted.

Comment: Are you scraping a web page?

Comment: [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net/) is an HTML parser written in C# to read/write DOM and supports plain XPATH or XSLT.

Comment: Yes I am scraping a web page. Well spotted.

Comment: The Html Agility Pack is an excellent tool and will be part of the solution. It will get the content of the <script> tag. Now to parse the javascript variable...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use [HTML Agility](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/) pack. This can be downloaded as a Nuget Package. 
After installing, this is a [tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack) on how to use HTML Agility pack.
The link has more info but it works like this in code:

```
var urlLink = "http://www.google.com/jsonPage"; // 1. Specify url where the json is to read. 

var web = new HtmlWeb(); // Init the HTMl Web

var doc = web.Load (urlLink); // Load our url

if (doc.ParseErrors != null) { // Check for any errors and deal with it. 
}

doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(""); // Access the dom.
```

There are other things in between but this should get you started.